# Block company domain from apache website how?

Tags: htaccess, apache

so I am running a site on apache. I want to block all visitors from domain *.xyz.com

I tried adding the following in .htaccess file:

```
<Files *>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from .*example\.com.*
</Files>
```

this didnt work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Tried just putting `.example.com`? e.g `.btcentralplus.com` no need to use 
`.*` `\ ` or `.*`

Answer (score 1):

Not really. A webserver does not directly know the domain of its users which they may not even have one, in fact.

It does know the referrer, if sent but that only can protect you from a link from a certain domain. They can easily spoofed too, so when used referral discrimination is more of a deterrent than protection. A person that types the URL directly though sends no referrer.

What the server must know is the IP the request is coming which is where it serves the response to. If you want to block people whose machines are within a certain domain, you must block them by IP. Even so, proxies and VPNs can add a relay which effectively changes the IP address of requests.

To block by IP you put in the .htaccess a statement like:

```
deny from 192.168.*.*
```

Or:

```
deny from 192.168.0.0/16
```

To do this you have to figure out the IP range for the company or domain you are trying to block. In a few cases that use some kind of gateway, it may be even just one IP address, in others there may be quite a few.

Comment: You can block based on hostname too :)

Comment: To get the hostname of a visitor, not the one of the webserver, you need to do a reverse lookup by IP. It is easy to do in PHP but I have never done that in the .htaccess. There might be a module to do that though.

Comment: Most web servers can be configured to provide the domain name. It is the default with Apache last I looked.

Comment: Apache does a reverse query as needed. But this is pretty useless as an authentication method...